# knex can't create SQLlite database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, knex.js

Im trying compile a migration to create a Database in knex , but when I execute

```
npx knex migrate:latest
```

on my powershell ,this happens:

```
Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
```

I already install sqlite3 in the knex site , and I already try search , but found nothing

Knex file:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './database/db.sqlite'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './migrations'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    },
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: check weather the file is already there `./database/db.sqlite`, if not create it

Comment: well the file is not there , the file should be created but its not creating the file.

Comment: maybe it doesn't get generated by knex so try creating it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have permission.
If you using Linux, run this in your directory: `sudo chmod -R 777 ./`.